Render an inline formula in a markdown cell of a notebook on vscode
I'm trying to render an inline formula in a markdown cell of an ipynb notebook on vscode, for example $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$, but it does not render, even after the command notebook.renderAllMarkdownCells.
Therefore, that is well rendered on a markdown file preview after calling markdown.showPreview.
What do I miss ?
(I have the extension Markdown Math).
